# SerializationException on one machine and not on another

Tags: c#, tfs, mailchimp, servicestack-text

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and TFS for a project. My colleague and I have machines with Windows 8.1 and Windows 8 respectively, both pointing to same database. Both machines have latest .NET framework installed.

Till now all was fine, until I added nuget package MailChimp.NET, It also have dependency on ServiceStack.Text. It threw below error on just my machine for any mailchimp API calls

> Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type
>   'ApiError', got string starting with: `<HTML>`
>
> `<HEAD>`
>
> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" co`

I tried same on my collegues machine and all works fine. Even if I copy paste whole solution to my local machine and run, there is same serializationException.

This is where only my machine throws error

> at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType(Type type, String strType, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, Dictionary`2 typeAccessorMap)

Anything I am missing due to which this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not due to different windows or .NET version but due to proxy used in the organization. The dll of mailchimp uses `WebRequest` which did not bring any json as proxy was not added, and thus error on deserialization.

Add proxy settings to web.config as below and the problem is solved.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://youraddress:port" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```